# Extracting message content in SIM900

Tags: c, gsm

Hi all I am interfacing with GSM SIM900 with atmega32. I am trying to extract the message contents. User will send message  like CHANGE7532167845 to SIM installed in GSM device. So to extract this I am using for loop followed by many if conditions. All I need to do is to save the number in a another variable. Following is my code:

```
for(int k =0; smscontent[k]!=NULL;k++)
        {
            if (smscontent[k] == 'C')
            {
                if (smscontent[k+1] == 'H')
                {
                    if (smscontent[k+2] == 'A')
                    {
                        if (smscontent[k+3] == 'N')
                        {
                            if (smscontent[k+4] == 'G')
                            {
                                if (smscontent[k+5] == 'E')
                                {


                                    if(isdigit(smscontent[k+6]))
                                    {
                                        serial_Tx("MATCH");

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            }
```

My control is reaching `isdigit` because on terminal I am getting MATCH but after that what I should do to save number in a variable.? Please help

serial_Tx function

```
void serial_Tx(char *str)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0;str[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        UDR=str[i];
        while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE))); 


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out some basic string handling tutorials.

I would suggest using strstr (C) or string::find (C++) instead of an elaborate if-if-if.

```
//C++
std::size_t found = smscontent.find("CHANGE");
if (found!=std::string::npos){
   std::string valueString = smscontent.substr(found+6/*strlen("CHANGE")*/);
   int value = std::stoi(valueString,nullptr);
}
```

I actually have no idea if the code above compiles or is anything like you're searching for.

```
//C
char buffer[20] = {'\0'};
int value = 0;
char * pposition = strstr(smscontent,"CHANGE");
ptrdiff_t position = pposition - smscontent;

if(pposition != NULL){
   strcpy(buffer, pposition);
   value = atoi(buffer);
}
```

There might be way easier options though, especially when using C++ or sscanf (if possible)

simply:

```
sscanf(smscontent,"CHANGE%u",value);
```

and the value will be saved in the variable: "value"

Comment: ok so you mean to say by using strstr we can search for CHANGE and then using pointer, we will copy it in buffer, is it?

Comment: error: unknown type ptrdiff_t, do we need to include any header file for it? I think cstddef.h need to be included and this is for C++ I am in C

Comment: it's in `stdio.h` for me, but it's `typedef int  ptrdiff_t;` so you could get away with a regular int I guess.

Comment: hey I have extracted the number and saved it in newnum which is a char. Now I am doing sprintf(call,"ATD%s;\r\n",newnum); and then serial_Tx(call); where serial_Tx is a function which transmit data serially but I am not getting any call.

Comment: `%s` would specify a string (char array)? And newnum was a char. Also, an (unsigned) char can only hold up values from 0 to 255. And be sure to send the serial string to the SIM900 modem and not just to your terminal/debug/screen

Comment: Oh I am sorry I forgot to tell you that newnum is char array because it will contain 10digit number

Comment: Ah! That makes the issue a bit easier actually, we don't have to convert to a number then. But, for the calling, [a] Be sure your SIMcard supports calls, many M2M sim-cards do not support calls. [b] Check if you're registered to a network (look up "AT+CREG?" and "AT+COPS?" commands). [c] Did it work with a constant string? Or does it only fail with the saved number/string you use

Comment: My sim card is registered and I have already made the call using the sim card from my gsm module but the problem is when I sprintf(call,"ATD%s;\r\n",newnum); and then serial_Tx(call); I only get ATD9654342168 and not the ; and not even \r\n. I think thats the size issue of CHAR. what can i do for that?

Comment: The `call` char array must be 3 (ATD) + 10 (numbers) + 3 (;\r\n) thus atleast 17 long (with a string termination '\0'?). And the serial_Tx() should output to the SIM900 module. Basically you could do `char call[18];`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26456/discussion-between-anna-carolina-and-fuaze).